# how to validate url with end of .xml regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have created a url field and submit button.and i want to validate this url like that it will show .xml regular expression at the end of url instead of .com and anything else. I have tried this code but didn't get reliable solution.It's redirecting me on another page when i writes invalid url.

Please help me through this . Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
function validateURL(){
var re = /^(http[s]?:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\.]{0,1}/.xml;
if (!re.test(url)) { 
alert("url error");
document.getElementById("error_msg").innerHTML = "invalid url";

return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Regex like `/.*\.xml$/` will match any string ending with `.xml`

Comment: @evolutionxbox....this regular expression will return this string http://admin.xml as valid url??

Comment: My comment wasn't an answer, but something to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this RegEX

```
/(https?!:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})/
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP has asked for, and it also doesn't match URLs without a www subdomain...